# R: How can I use loop variable i in the extract symbol $ of a dataframe?

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression

For example, consider a data frame df consists of 3 variables v1,v2,v3.

```
v1=rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=2)
v2=rnorm(10,mean=2,sd=2)
v3=rnorm(10,mean=3,sd=2)
df=data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
```

And now I want to use for loop to do linear regression:

```
for (i in names(df)){
  fit <- lm(i~.,data=df)
}
```

Here comes an error. What I want is to run loop variable i from v1 to v3, however the loop variable i is actually "v1" to "v3". How can I deal with this?

I know some other ways, such as use df[,i] instead of i in the formular, however, when I predict with a newdata, it will cause error:

```
train <- df[1:5,]
test <- df[6:10,]

for (i in names(df)){
  fit <- lm(train[,i]~.,data=train)
  predict<- predict(fit,newdata=test[,!(colnames(test) %in% i)])
}
```

Plus, I really want to use ~. instead of ~v2+v3, because in fact I have 200 variables.

Really hoping for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute on the language:

```
for (i in names(df)){
  y <- as.name(i)
  fit <- eval(bquote(lm(.(y) ~ ., data = train)))
  predict <- predict(fit, newdata = test)
}
```

Comment: Compare the formula in `print(fit)` with what you get from @jlesuffleur's answer. My solution is safer because it avoids potential scoping issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `formula`:

```
for (i in names(df)){
  form <- formula(paste0(i, "~."))
  fit <- lm(form, data = df)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. It works well! So sorry that my reputation is less than 15, thus vote is not displayed.